# How to stock each line of a file to be able to sort a random string of it?

Tags: python

I have to make a random sorting generator in python. For this I have to open a file given as an argument and the data the user want from the file given in argument too. For example the user enter the file `toto.txt` and in it we got

```
name = toto, tata, titi
age = 10, 22, 33, 54, 65, 78
power = fire, snow, strength, water
```

but it can get more and with different names for each start of lines.

So when he will execute the program he should put `python toto.py text_file.txt name power`, and from that I have to sort randomly one of the different value from the `name` and `power` lines.

But how can I check all the arguments he inputs to the program ?

First I wanted to use `sys.arg` to get his input but then I though that I will have to stock this in a variable because he could put only one argument but he could also put like 10-20 arguments too so I won't create 20 variable to store all of it. So I would like to know if there is a way to check and store each argument to be able to parse my file using those arguments.

For The moment the only thing I have is the function to open my file and check all the file content in a variable.

Here is a little expectation of what the program should do.

```
file.txt content(not always the same content):

birth = 10, 20, 45, 5
name = toto, tta, tote, thi, sazkpo
town = LA, miami, new-york, las-vegas
size = 2m, 4m, 5m, 3m
car = audi, golf, opel

user input : 

python binary file.txt name size car

def ggget_data_from_file(all the arguments input = name size and car):
 open the file.txt
 while in the file:
  looking for name line
  when he find it sort a random value from this line
 does this for all argument, in this case (name size and car)

sorting expected = tta, 5m, golf
```

Comment: Why do you have to create a variable for each argument? Why not use `sys.argv[2:]`, which is a list?

Comment: @wjandrea If I do that, how should I get the data he asked in argv[5] ? For example if the user ask something like ```./binary file.txt toto tata titi``` if I use your way, I will stock all of my inputs in a variable but then how can I parse my file to sort the values he asked me in second or the last value ? Because I wanted to acccess each line by comparing the inputs and the line to see if I find a match, and then I apply a random in it before the sorting. I don't know if it's clear

Comment: Hmm, it's not really clear. Could you make a [mre], maybe including pseudocode for the part you're asking about?

Comment: I edit the to have a "program expectation" have a look on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply iterate over each argument in `sys.argv[2:]`.

Based on your pseudocode:

```
import sys

def get_data_from_file(filename, args):
    with open(filename) as file:
        for arg in args:
            line = find(file, arg)
            yield pick_random(line)

data = get_data_from_file('file.txt', sys.argv[2:])
print(', '.join(data))
```

Note that `find` and `pick_random` are not defined. Those are up to you.

Also this is not optimized. In practice you'll probably want to iterate over each line of `file` and check if it matches any of `args`.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of choices here.  Whenever I do command line scripts, I use the [click library](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/), it takes care of alot of the overhead and simplifies the help strings, type checking etc.

Once you understand how the library works, then you can check out the  [multi value options section](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/options/#multi-value-options)